# Design or Algorithm to Validate a Pattern of Data in DataTable C#

Tags: algorithm, validation, design-patterns, datatable

I have a very weird situation.
I have a Excel file with data like

Header data_xyz
       A|B|C
  datA  1|2|3
  datB  1|2|3
  datC  1|2|3
.
.
.
.
END of Pattern
Recurring Pattern
Header data_xyz
       A|B|C
  datA  1|2|3
  datB  1|2|3
  datC  1|2|3
.
.
.
.
END of Pattern

Now we need to validate the data in columns A,B,C is Numeric and similarly check the datA,datB be not empty .

Rules will be:

1. No of data rows in pattern differ
2. Each Pattern is defined so any data other than pattern will be invaid

Can we use some design to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) library. You can use it to import your excel file into a C# data table. You can run your logic on each row using loops. If any of the rows do not meet the specified criteria you can perform your desired actions. For validation purposes or pattern matching you can use Regex. As a newbie I can say that if you haven't learned it yet, please do. It will help you a long way. Good luck brother.